# Comparing Two NSDates with specific constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am working to accomplish within 3 statements, a check that compares two times (stored as NSDates) and executes code based on the difference between the two respectively. the checks I am wishing to implement are ( < 3min ), ( > 3min < 3hrs ), and ( > 3hrs ). Below is my most recent attempt. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, Thank You!

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@""];
[df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a MM-dd-yyyy"];

NSDate* newDate = [df dateFromString:[df stringFromDate:[[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributeForKey:@"date_time_edt"]]];

NSTimeInterval interval = [newDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

if(interval < 3 * 60) {
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tire_green.png"];
    NSLog(@"%@", newDate);
    NSLog(@"%f", interval);
}
else if(interval > 3 * 60  && interval < 3 * 60 * 60) {
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tire_yellow.png"];
    NSLog(@"%@", newDate);
}
else {
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tire_red.png"];
    NSLog(@"%@", newDate);
}
```

Comment: Reread (or look at for the first time) the documentation for NSCalendar.

Comment: Note: `timeIntervalSinceDate:` is in seconds, not minutes.

Comment: Is there an issue with using the value of `timeIntervalSinceDate:` for the `???`s?

Comment: No issue, @JoshCaswell just was unable to determine what variable was most significant for this placeholder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated based on the far too long comment thread.

It turns out that `[[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributeForKey:@"date_time_edt"]` is returning an `NSNumber` representing the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970. So there is no need for any date formatters. You can get a date from this value as follows (which needs seconds, not milliseconds):

```
NSNumber *timestamp = [[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributeForKey:@"date_time_edt"];
NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[timestamp doubleValue] / 1000];
```

Now you can get the time interval since "now". Keep in mind that the resulting interval will be negative if `newDate` is in the past (which is true in your case).

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [newDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

Since you know that `interval` will always be negative since `newDate` will always be in the past, your checks will be easier if we make it positive.

```
interval = -interval; // now positive
```

Now you can do the needed checks to get the desired image.

```
if (interval < 3 * 60) { // < 3 minutes
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tire_green.png"];
} else if (interval > 3 * 60 * 60) { // > 3 hours
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tire_red.png"];
} else { // >= 3 minutes && <= 3 hours
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tire_yellow.png"];
}
```

Comment: I have tried this fix and find that a greater issue lies in the format of the dates. The error I am receiving is "[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d21350"

Comment: That would imply that `[[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributeForKey:@"date_time_edt"]` is returning an `NSNumber` and not an `NSString`.

Comment: Within the debugger the value is = (NSDate *)0x4088c00000000000.

Comment: It's not an `NSDate`. It's an `NSNumber`. That's what the error states.

Comment: I have updated the code in the first section, does the formatting matter necessarily when determining the difference between two NSDates (considering they are returned in seconds)?

Comment: The formatting only matters when trying to convert an `NSString` to an `NSDate`. Once you have the two `NSDate` objects, the original format of the strings is irrelevant.

Comment: I find this to be true, I am returning Null for                                                      newDate = [df dateFromString:[df stringFromDate:[[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributeForKey:@"date_time_edt"]]]

Comment: Such code makes no sense. If `[[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributeForKey:@"date_time_edt"]` is already an `NSDate` then why convert it to a string and then back to an `NSDate`?

Comment: the attribute date_time_edt is returned as a JSON representation that is parsed from a string (than presumably into an NSNumber given the previous errors). for example this is returned by an entry: 1438608176000

Comment: If `[[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributeForKey:@"date_time_edt"]` returns an `NSNumber` than you can't call `stringFromDate:` on the `NSNumber`. You can get an `NSDate` from the `NSNumber` in this case using `NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:`. Pass in the `doubleValue` of the `NSNumber` divided by 1000. No date formatter should be used for this.

Comment: Presently, it is working but returning negative. But what you've suggested definitely works Thank You!                                                            NSDate* newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributeForKey:@"date_time_edt"] doubleValue]/1000]                                                                       returning: -1219746.894686

Comment: That can't be returning a negative number. Logging an `NSDate` would not show a number, it would show a date.

Comment: You're correct the interval I have NSTimeInterval interval = [newDate timeIntervalSinceNow]; is retuning negative. I also am using this in the check cases.

Comment: Ok, that value is negative. That makes much more sense. That simply means that newDate is in th past. Read the docs for timeIntervalSinceNow.

Comment: This makes sense, a better question is how do I get the difference between the current time and the date object I pass a message to (which I was under the presumption that timeIntervalSinceNow accomplished this and returned the answer in seconds) and store this as the interval for comparison.

Comment: @ChavezJenningsVisions See my updated answer which should cover everything you need.

Comment: Thank You, it is working! I was overthinking things slightly not considering that the radios are updated merely twice a week. Either way, your help and prompt responses have been greatly appreciated.